# Custom page in archive page for certain category

Tags: pages, archives

In my archive page I want a certain category not to display. The rest of the code I'm adding, but it goes to a custom page

The logic is like, if is `category=33`, then include photo.php

```
<div class="latest_from_category">


<h2 class="latest_frm_cat_title archive_title"><?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
<?php /* If this is a category archive */
 if (is_category()) { 
        ?>
   <?php 
     _e('', 'bilanti'); ?> 
   '<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>' 
    <?php _e('Archive For', 'bilanti'); ?>                                  

   <?php /* If this is a tag archive */  
    } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
   <?php _e('Archive for the', 'bilanti'); ?> 
   <?php single_tag_title(); ?> Tag

  <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ 
    } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
  <?php _e('Archive for', 'bilanti'); ?> 
  <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>                                     

  <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ 
  } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
  <?php _e('Archive for', 'bilanti'); ?>
  <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>                                    

  <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ 
   } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
 <?php _e('Archive for', 'bilanti'); ?> 
 <?php the_time('Y'); ?>

  <?php /* If this is a search */ 
    } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
    <?php _e('Search Results', 'bilanti'); ?>

    <?php /* If this is an author archive */ 
        } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
        <?php _e('Author Archive', 'bilanti'); ?>

        <?php /* If this is a paged archive */
    } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>

    <?php _e('Blog Archives', 'bilanti'); ?>                                        
    <?php } ?></h2> 
   <?php get_template_part( 'post-excerpt' ); // Post Excerpt (post-excerpt.php) ?>

   <?php else : ?>
  <h3 class="archive_not_found">404 <span>not found</span></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>                           
    </div>
```

What should the exact code be?

Comment: Please indent your code properly before you add it to your question. As it stand, I can't read it (and most other people, specially mobile users) as most of your code is outside the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) conditionally.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpsites_photo_page_template', 99 );

function wpsites_photo_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_category('33') ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'photo.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: i was thinking n searching for something like this thanx

Answer (score 0):

Well, the template hierarchy allows you to use a custom template file for categories.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display

If you want a special template for the category 33, you just save the template file as category-33.php in the theme folder.

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: yup i already found it thanx anyway